# Ring of tangent circles inscribed in another circle

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

My question is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779068/how-do-i-draw-x-number-of-circles-around-a-central-circle-starting-at-the-top-o/42405249#42405249).
The code of the post is fantastic.

It creates a ring of satellite circles tangent to a base circle (Out of the base circle).

This part calculates the radius external to the circle:

```
var angle = Math.PI / n;
var s = Math.sin(angle);
var r = baseRadius * s / (1-s);
```

**How to calculate the radius of the circles if I want the circle ring to be tangent inside the base circle?**

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You mean you want them inside like this? http://imgur.com/a/gLNgW

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you very much. Inner tangent circles to the main circle.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your sub circles by `Sine` and `Cosine` and `PI`.

You can use this as a baseline:

```js
//Classes
var Coord = (function() {
  function Coord(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  return Coord;
}());
var Circle = (function() {
  function Circle(origo, radius) {
    this.origo = origo;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  Circle.prototype.circumference = function() {
    return this.radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  };
  return Circle;
}());
//functions
function innerTangentCircles(master, count) {
  if (count === void 0) {
    count = 4;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    var cos = Math.cos(((Math.PI * 2) / count) * index);
    var sin = Math.sin(((Math.PI * 2) / count) * index);
    var circle = new Circle(new Coord(master.origo.x + (master.radius * cos) - (master.radius / (count / 2)) * cos, master.origo.y + (master.radius * sin) - (master.radius / (count / 2)) * sin), master.radius / (count / 2));
    result.push(circle);
  }
  return result;
}
//>>Test<<
//Create circles
var bigC = new Circle(new Coord(200, 200), 200);
//Create DOM
var c = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
c.canvas.width = 500;
c.canvas.height = 500;
document.body.appendChild(c.canvas);
//Run loop
function draw(i) {
  var circles = innerTangentCircles(bigC, i);
  c.fillStyle = "red";
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(bigC.origo.x, bigC.origo.y, bigC.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
  c.fillStyle = "yellow";
  for (var index = 0; index < circles.length; index++) {
    var circle = circles[index];
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(circle.origo.x, circle.origo.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();
  }
  if (i > 500) {
    i = 4;
  }
  i = i * 2;
  setTimeout(function() {
    draw(i);
  }, 1000);
}
draw(8);
```

Comment: I thank you in advance for your efforts.

What I would like is for the inner circles to be tangent to each other and tangents to the outer circle.

In the post example I put, the circles are tangent to each other and tangent to the base circle, (externally)

I would really like to know how to calculate the radius of the circles.

I include a code that shows how the radius of the external circles (for n circles)

Could you help me please?

I say many thanks for your help.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * Coord
 */
var Coord = (function() {
  function Coord(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  return Coord;
}());
/**
 * Circle
 */
var Circle = (function() {
  function Circle(origo, radius) {
    this.origo = origo;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  Circle.radiusFromCircumference = function(circumference) {
    return circumference / Math.PI / 2;
  };
  Circle.circumference = function(radius) {
    return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  };
  Circle.prototype.circumference = function() {
    return Circle.circumference(this.radius);
  };
  return Circle;
}());
//Functions
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}

function getRadian(count, index) {
  return ((Math.PI * 2) / count) * index;
}

function circlesFromCircumference(master, count) {
  var circles = [];
  var masterCircumference = master.circumference();
  var innerRadius = Circle.radiusFromCircumference(masterCircumference);
  //var innerCircumference = Circle.circumference(innerRadius);
  var circleRadius = 0;
  var radian = getRadian(count, 1);
  var maxCalc = 1000;
  while (maxCalc--) {
    var dist = distance(Math.cos(0) * innerRadius + master.origo.x, Math.sin(0) * innerRadius + master.origo.y, Math.cos(radian) * innerRadius + master.origo.x, Math.sin(radian) * innerRadius + master.origo.y);
    if (Math.abs(dist / 2 - circleRadius) < 0.5) {
      break;
    }
    circleRadius = dist / 2;
    innerRadius = master.radius - circleRadius;
  }
  for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    var radian = getRadian(count, index);
    var cos = Math.cos(radian);
    var sin = Math.sin(radian);
    var c = new Circle(new Coord(cos * innerRadius + master.origo.x, sin * innerRadius + master.origo.y), circleRadius);
    circles.push(c);
  }
  return circles;
}
//>>TEST<<
var c = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
c.canvas.height = 200;
c.canvas.width = c.canvas.height;
document.body.appendChild(c.canvas);
var bigC = new Circle(new Coord(c.canvas.height / 2, c.canvas.height / 2), c.canvas.height / 2.1);

function draw(size) {
  size++;
  c.fillStyle = "red";
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(bigC.origo.x, bigC.origo.y, bigC.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
  var circles = circlesFromCircumference(bigC, size);
  c.fillStyle = "yellow";
  for (var index = 0; index < circles.length; index++) {
    var circle = circles[index];
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(circle.origo.x, circle.origo.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (size > 32) {
      size = 2;
    }
    draw(size);
  }, 1000 / 4);
}
draw(1);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. That's what I was looking for but I still do not know how the radius of the inner tangent circles is caculated.

That code is very complex for me. To calculate the radius is posible do a simple function like:

Function GetInnerTangentGirclesRadius (basecircleRadio, count) {

Return InnerTangentRadio
}

Comment: And it would also be great to be able to do the same calculation but with a separation between the circles.

Function GetInnerTangentGirclesRadius (basecircleRadio, count, gap) {

Return InnerTangentRadioWithGap
}


I know it's too much to ask. I'm sorry to be so clumsy (I'm a rookie and I'm not a programmer)

I apologize for the inconvenience and thank you very much for helping me.

a greeting